# .Net 3.5 SP1 official update rollout?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, deployment

To the best of my knowledge and googling skills, .Net 3.5 SP1 is still not an "official" release.  That is the only way to get the SP1 upgrade is by voluntary download and not through mandatory windows updates.

Is there any time frame set for when .Net 3.5 SP1 will be pushed to all windows users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scott Hanselman wrote up the skinny on this:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NET35SP1GDRIsAvailableToDownload.aspx

*"As of today, we are still on track for 2009Q1 availability of 3.5 SP1 on Windows Update"*

Answer (score 0):

Follow up: the update is available in Windows Update, it appears as "Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Family Update" or such.